# matlab - extracting numbers from (odd) string

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a series of strings in a cvs file, they all look like the two bellow:

```
7336598,"[4125420656L, 2428145712L, 1820029797L, 1501679119L, 1980837904L, 380501274L]"
7514340,"[507707719L, 901144614L, 854823005L]"
....
```

how can I extract the numbers in it?
As in.. to retreive 7336598, 4125420656, etc....

Tried `textscan`, and `regexp`, but not much success...

Sorry for the beginners question...and thank you for having a look! :)

Edit: the size of each line is variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) and [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to extract only the numbers from your CSV file:

```
C = textread('file.cvs', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
C = regexp(C, '\d+', 'match');
```

The regular expression is quite simple. In MATLAB's `regexp` pattern,`\d` denotes a digit, and the `+` indicates that this digit must occur at least once. The `match` mode tells `regexp` to return the matched strings.

The result is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of strings. You can go further and convert the strings to numerical values:

```
C = cellfun(@(x)str2num(sprintf('%s ', x{:})), C, 'Uniform', false)
```

The result is still stored in a cell array. If you can guarantee that there's the same amount of numerical values in each row, you can convert the cell array to a matrix:

```
A = cell2mat(C);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!! I forgot to mention however that the size of each line is variable... it can contain more numbers than the six in my example.... any further ideas at all?.... in advance: thank you so much!!

Comment: It does indeed - sorry!! thank you so much.. will do some testing, and mark your answer as accepted! :)  THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have matlab to test, but does a '[0-9]+' does the job ?

It works for me outside matlab :

```
echo '7336598,"[4125420656L, 2428145712L, 1820029797L, 1501679119L, 1980837904L, 380501274L]"' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
7336598
4125420656
2428145712
1820029797
1501679119
1980837904
380501274
```

Comment: in matlab, I tried regexp with [0-9], but only to get individual numbers: "7", "3", "3",.... :S:S not exactly what i wanted!! surely I am doing something wrong...