# Getting numerical value from edit box in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've designed a GUI with `resize` option in it. Where user is allowed to enter image size in 2 provided edit boxes.

```
function x_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to x (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
user_entry_X = str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
if isnan(user_entry_X)
 errordlg('You must enter a numeric value','Bad Input','modal')
 uicontrol(hObject)
return
end
```

above code is for `edit box` `X`. If user gives non-numerical input it results in error. But I'm not getting how to fetch entered numeric values. I've a `pushbutton` named `resize`, on pressing that after entering numbers in edit box image should get resize. 
What should i use in my `resize_callback` function? please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of the edit box with

```
S = get(editBoxHandle, 'string');
```

If it's a numerical value, then convert it

```
N = str2num(S);
```

If you want to have only the digits within a string mixing letters and numbers, this code

```
S = '123abc456xyz';
N = cell2mat(regexp(S, '\d+', 'match')); 
disp(N)
```

gives `N=123456` (from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549664/matlab-extracting-numbers-from-odd-string)).

Comment: Thank you, well how can i clear the same edit box? I've a push button with name `reset`. after pressing that edit box should show zero values in the sense nothing should present.

Comment: The twin function of get will give you the control of the edit box content: `set(editBoxHandle, 'string','')` where `''` stands for the empty string.