# Function to split string in matlab and return second number

Tags: matlab

I have a string and I need two characters to be returned. 
I tried with `strsplit` but the delimiter must be a string and I don't have any delimiters in my string. Instead, I always want to get the second number in my string. The number is always 2 digits.

Example: 001a02.jpg I use the fileparts function to delete the extension of the image (jpg), so I get this string: 001a02 
The expected return value is 02

Another example: 001A43a . Return values: 43

Another one: 002A12. Return values: 12

All the filenames are in a matrix 1002x1. Maybe I can use `textscan` but in the second example, it gives "43a" as a result.

Comment: What can you say about the character used to split? is it always an uppercase or a lowercase letter? Is the part you want to keep always a number? Do you always want to return the 2nd number in your string? Is the required number always of length 2? Why don't you just take the 5th and 6th characters from the string? Also - what generated these filenames? Maybe you can take advantage of that logic somehow... It's possible that you could use some `regex` to parse this - but there currently isn't enough information to suggest an appropriate answer. Please include this info in your question :)

Comment: 1) Letters are lowercase and uppercase
2) yes, I want to keep just 2 numbers
3) Yes, always the second number
4) Yes, length 2.
5) I don't know how to take the 5th and 6th character

Comment: I found the solution! Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just so this question doesn't remain unanswered, here's a possible approach: )

One way to go about this uses splitting with regular expressions (MATLAB's [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) which you mentioned):

```
str = '001a02.jpg';
C = strsplit(str,'[a-zA-Z.]','DelimiterType','RegularExpression');
```

Results in:

```
C = 
    '001'    '02'    ''
```

In older versions of MATLAB, before `strsplit` was introduced, similar functionality was achieved using [`regexp(...,'split')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqcpjk-4).

If you want to learn more about regular expressions (abbreviated as "*regex*" or "*regexp*"), there are many online resources (JGI..)

In your case, if you only need to take the 5th and 6th characters from the string you could use:

```
D = str(5:6);
```

... and if you want to convert those into numbers you could use:

```
E = str2double(str(5:6));
```

Comment: Simultaneous answers!

Comment: Which version of Matlab  was strsplit added?

Comment: Yeah, hehe :) Note that I used `str2double` instead of `str2num`, as this is generally safer (according to the [`str2num` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html#zmw57dd0e667695)). According to [this page](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility#MATLAB_8.1_.28R2013a.29), `strsplit` was added in MATLAB 2013a.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is always at a certain position in the string, you can simply index this position.

In the examples you gave, the number is always the 5th and 6th characters in the string.

```
filename = '002A12';
num = str2num(filename(5:6));
```

Otherwise, if the formating is more complex, you may want to use a regular expression. There is a similar question [matlab - extracting numbers from (odd) string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549664/matlab-extracting-numbers-from-odd-string). Modifying the code found there you can do the following

```
all_num = regexp(filename, '\d+', 'match'); %Find all numbers in the filename 
num = str2num(all_num{2}) %Convert second number from str
```